# Average Branching factor with implicit graphs

Tags: graphs

i have to calculate the average branching factor of the given successor function(pseudo-code) for every $m,n \in N$:

```
succ (x,y) = {(x-1 `mod` m, y), (x+1 `mod` m, y), (x, y-1 `mod` n), (x, y+1 `mod` n)}
```

with $n \geq m^{2}+2, n \geq 1$ and `{}` represent a mathematical set.

What i know is that the average branching factor is the sum of all outdegrees divided by the amount of nodes(without leaves).

Comment: The set always contains four elements (for $m > 2$). Is that what you're interested in?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I acknowledged that too, but is the answer so simple?

Comment: What is the definition of "average branching factor"?  What do you mean by that in this context?  What do you mean by "outdegrees" in this context?  What are the nodes, leaves, and what is the tree here?  If you need to compute these things, you should check your textbook / course notes to see how they are defined.  If you can't find the answer there, you should ask your instructor or whoever set you this problem what they mean by those terms.